# Access Flask config as attributes rather than dict keys

Tags: python, flask

When handling application config in Flask, it's usually recommended to use the `config` dictionary available on the `flask.Flask` object, e.g. `flask.current_app.config["TESTING"]`.

One recommendation for populating this is to use classes and inheritance to separate config per environment:

```
class Config:
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user@localhost/foo'

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True

# Example usage:
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(ProductionConfig)

db_uri = app.config["DATABASE_URI"]
```

The disadvantage to this is that despite having defined our keys using class attributes, we access them using string keys, which end up being referenced around the code. If I mistype a key, I won't get a warning in my IDE and will get a `KeyError` at runtime. I also don't get type inference for the objects in the config.

It would be nice to be able to populate the Flask config in a similar way, but have better access to these values, like I might access ordinary attributes on an object.

I've thought of a few approaches, but none of them quite seem ideal:

1. Wrap every config key in a function e.g. `get_database_uri()` - as long as this is the only way the config is accessed, the available keys and the types of their values are known. Requires writing a function for every new config key.
2. Store a single `Config` object within the Flask config e.g. `app.config["config"] = ProductionConfig()`. With a type hint or wrapper function, we get typing, but it's odd to store a config object inside a config, and we lose the automatic setting of Flack-specific values such as `TESTING`.
3. Forget about using `app.config`, and use any other solution.

Has anyone found any cleaner solutions which also integrate with Flask's config?

Answer (score 4):

The class used for [`app.config`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.config) can be configured by overriding [`Flask.config_class`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.config_class). Write a subclass of [`flask.config.Config`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Config) that defines [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) to look up keys, and assign it to the `config_class` attribute.

```py
from flask.app import Flask
from flask.config import Config

class AttrConfig(Config):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

    def __dir__(self):
        out = set(self.keys())
        out.update(super().__dir__())
        return sorted(out)

class CustomFlask(Flask):
    config_class = AttrConfig

app = CustomFlask(__name__)
```

There's no reliable way to make IDEs understand these attributes though, given that they are loaded dynamically. Implementing `__dir__` will make them show up in tab completion from the Python or IPython shell, but IDEs generally don't execute module code to provide introspection, so this won't affect them.